# confusion regarding multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am actually very beginner in java field and currently going through multithreading concepts

I came across a program and had certain doubts regarding the program itself.

Following is my program

```
public class SecondThreadDemo implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

class B implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        new SecondThreadDemo().run();
        new SecondThreadDemo().run();
        new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").run();
        new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T2").start();
        new SecondThreadDemo().run();
        new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").start();
    }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new B(), "T1").start();
    }
}..
```

Now what I was expecting is the following output

```
T1T1T1T1T3T3
```

but its coming like

```
T1T1T1T1T2T3
```

Can someone clarify the output?

Comment: There's a difference between `run` and `start`.  `Runnable` itself isn't a `Thread` so it will execute inline with the rest of your code (like calling any other method).  `start` schedules a thread which will can `run` of your `Runnable`, in your example.  There will also be differences each time you run it and it come down to how the thread scheduling is working

Comment: @MadProgrammer t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶u̶s̶e̶s̶ ̶m̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶h̶y̶ ̶O̶P̶'̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶d̶e̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶`̶T̶2̶`̶ ̶t̶w̶i̶c̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶u̶t̶p̶u̶t̶  nevermind OP already fixed this. Turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: Sorry I paster wrong output.Correction made >please excuse me

Comment: @Thegoodthebadtheugly Once you start hitting the `start` point of your threads, it becomes impossible to predict the output to any level of accuracy...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a difference between `run` and `start`.

`Runnable` itself isn't a `Thread` so it will execute inline with the rest of your code (like calling any other method).

`start` schedules a thread which will can `run` of your `Runnable`, in your example.

There will also be differences each time you run it and it will come down to how the thread scheduling is working

For example, you code does this...

```
new SecondThreadDemo().run();
new SecondThreadDemo().run();
new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").run();
new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T2").start();
new SecondThreadDemo().run();
new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").start();
```

This would (possibly) output something like...

```
T1 (run)
T1 (run)
T1 (run) (cause I'm in T1's thread context)
// Then it all depends...this MIGHT be the output...
{T1} (run)
{T2} (start)
{T3} (start)
```

Comment: I guess you should add that the only thing guaranteed is that `T1` will be printed before `T3` in the last section.

Comment: I m confused at line 3 I have this at line 3---new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").run();   it should print T3 why it is giving output as T1 ie not getting in my head     Thanks

Comment: The 3rd line is printing T3, because you've called `run`.  All you've done is called the thread's run method, which immeditaly delegates to your `Runnable`'s `run` method.  It doesn't actually start a new thread...

Comment: But it is printing T1

Comment: @Thegoodthebadtheugly probably you used `T1` instead of `T3` in this line: `new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").run();` before executing the code (that's the only explanation).

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getName()` will return `T1` (on the 3rd line) because the current thread IS `T1`, you've just called the `run` method which is executed within the context of the `T1` thread

Comment: mad programer and luigi  I have somewhat understood .....So according to me if you claa run method it will continue in that thread method only and won't change the name of thread and as soon as you call start method and then call run method after this start method ......output becomes unpredictable......Is it correct or anuthing is missed .....Thanks

Comment: No.  Don't call `run`.  This is the most common mistake when learning and using `Thread`s.  Simply call `start`.  It will, once it's scheduled to, call `run` for you.  Basically, call `start` and sit back and wait...

Answer (score 0):

A new thread in java will spawn only if you call start method on thread, which will execute the code written in the run method in a new thread.

But if you directly call run() method on thread or runnable object then it will be executed in the main thread of execution not in a new thread.

Answer (score 0):

`new SecondThreadDemo().run();` - Simple Function call so T1 as running thread is T1

`new SecondThreadDemo().run();` - Simple Function call so T1 as running thread is T1

`new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").run();` - Simple Function call so T1 as running thread is T1

`new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T2").start();` -  At this point you are creating a thread with name T2 and calling start, here it depends it can print T2 or may be next line will get executed and will print T1 before this thread prints T2

`new SecondThreadDemo().run();` - T1 simple function call

`new Thread(new SecondThreadDemo(), "T3").start();` - T3 as expected

so it wil depend on JVM output can be T1T1T1T1T2T3 or may be T1T1T1T2T1T3